# What is the concept of this interface and private data type pattern

Tags: go, interface

I used the github.com/hooklift/gowsdl/soap , and I got generated code with this pattern

```
package funky

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Place struct {
    Text string
}

type RandomFunky interface {
    Buggy(b int)(int)
}

type randomFunky struct {
    place *Place
}

func NewFunky(p *Place) RandomFunky {
    return &randomFunky{
        place: p,
    }
    return nil  
}

func (rf * randomFunky) Buggy(b int)(int) {
    fmt.Println(rf.place.Text)
    return b
}
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "funky"
)

func main() {
    p := funky.Place{}
    p.Text = "o jee"

    f := funky.NewFunky(&p)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n",f) // type of "*funky.randomFunky"
    // var f *funky.randomFunky !!!  cannot refer to unexported name funky.randomFunky

    f.Buggy(1)  
}
```

"f" - I can get this type this way, but I can not create a var of this type!

- What if I want to store *funky.randomFunky var in the struct ?
- Or pass it to the function?
- Is this implies that I always have to recreate NewFunky every time I want to call Buggy method?
  (assuming Buggy called in multiple places and/or interface has more methods)
- Or should I modify the code and make *funky.randomFunky public?
- Or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the idea is that any variable/function/type/method starting with lowercase is local, and starting with uppercase is global. Local stuff can be used directly only inside the same package.

So in your case, `RandomFunky` is a global interface with a single method `Buggy`, and a `randomFunky` is a local structure, implementing `RandomFunky`, because it has the method `Buggy` with the same parameters.

In fact, `NewFunky` returns you a structure wrapped into an interface. So you can't use `randomFunky` outside the package `funky`, but you can use `funky.RandomFunky`.

In your case you can just create a variable of this type

```
...
var f funky.RandomFunky
f = funky.NewFunky(&p)
...
```

Comment: src/funky-demo/funky-demo.go:13:4: no new variables on left side of := , remove ':' and then it wokrs!

Comment: I did try declare  var f \*funky.RandomFunky an got error, Since it's var to interface, I guess it is pointer by default, so '*' is not needed! Thanks!

Comment: Technically the terms are "exported" and "unexported", not "global" and "local".

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I just like to call them "global" and "local" due to my ABAP background